# python - pandas dataframe processing

Tags: python, pandas

So I am back with another question about python and pandas.
I have table1 with following columns:

```
ID;COUNT;FOREIGN_ID;OTHER_DATA
1;3;xyz1
2;1;xyz2
3;1;xyz3
```

table2

```
ID;FOREIGN_ID;OTHER_DATA
1;xyz1;000001
2;xyz1;000002
3;xyz1;000003
4;xyz1;000004
5;xyz1;000005
6;xyz2;000000
7;xyz2;000000
8;xyz3;000000
9;xyz3;000000
```

Both tables are stored as CSV files. I load both of them into dataframe, and then iterate through TABLE1. I must find all records in table2 with same record and randomly select some of them.

```
df_result = pd.DataFrame()
df_table1 = pd.read_csv(table1, delimiter=';')
df_table2 = pd.read_csv(table2, delimiter=';')

for index, row in df_table1 .iterrows():
    df_candidates = df_table2[(df_table2['FOREIGN_ID'] == row['FOREIGN_ID']
    random_numbers = np.random.choice(len(df_kandidati), row['count'], replace=False)
    df_result.append(df_candidates.iloc[random_numbers])
```

In my earlier question I got an answer that using For loop is big time waster... But for this problem I can't find a solution where I wouldn't need to use for loop.

EDIT:
I am sorry for editing my question so late.. was busy with other stuff...
As requested below is the result_table. Please note that my real tables are slightly different than those below. I am joining tables on 3 foreign keys in my real use but for demonstration, I am using tables with fake data.

So the logic should be something like this: 
Read the first line of table1.

```
1;3;xyz1
```

Find all records with same FOREIGN_ID in table2
count = 3, foreign_id = xyz1
Rows with foreign_id = xyz1 are rows:

```
1;xyz1;000001
2;xyz1;000002
3;xyz1;000003
4;xyz1;000004
5;xyz1;000005
```

Because count = 3 I must randomly choose 3 of those records. 
I do this with the following line:
df_candidates is table of all suitable records (table above)

```
random_numbers = np.random.choice(len(df_candidates), row['count'], replace=False)
```

Then I store randomly chosen records in a df_result after parsing all rows from table1 I write df_result to the csv.

Problem is that my tables are 0.5milion - 1 milion rows big so iterating through every row in table1 is really slow... And I am sure there is a better way of doing this.. But I've been stuck on this for past 2 days so..

Comment: Can you show us the expected output?

Comment: you may use pandas [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

Comment: `table1.merge(table2, on='FOREIGN_ID')` and then randomly select rows.

Comment: What do you mean by "same record"?

Comment: I edited my question to further clarify my problem. please take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select rows, containing only values from Table1, you can use, for example, [pd.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) :

```
col = "FOREIGN_ID"

left = df_table2
right = df_table1[[col]]
filtered = pd.merge(left=left, right=right, on=col, how="inner")
```

Or [df.isin()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html):

```
ix = df_table2[col].isin(df_table1[col])
filtered = df_table2[ix]
```

Then to select random sample per group:

```
def select_random_row(grp):
    choice = np.random.randint(len(grp))
    return grp.iloc[choice]

filtered.groupby(col).apply(select_random_row)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. It does exactly what I wanted I just had to change select_random_row(grp) function to select #number of rows instead of only 1.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into using  [pd.merge()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

Your call would look something like:

```
results=pd.merge(table1, table2, how='inner', on='FOREIGN_ID')
```